# How can I segue or pop back to the second scene of the first tab in a tabbed app, from a scene on another tab?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a storyboard set up with a tab bar controller and three tabs. Each tab has a navigation controller. The first tab has three scenes. There is a button (log out) in a view on the third tab that I would like to segue to the second scene on the first tab (corresponding to the log in view controller and connected to the first scene via Show(e.g., Push).

Here is what I've tried:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

This works, insofar as I get back to the first tab's initial scene after tapping the UIButton. But since I want to get to the second scene, this is not a complete solution. I think the solution may be along the lines of:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = LoginViewController()
```

or

```
self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers(self.LoginViewController, animated: true)
```

But I do not want to create another instance of a view controller.

Can I still use .selectedIndex to implement a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution u can try is 
1. Set a Global variable (i.e in App Delegate) name as isLogoutClick of type boolean.
2. While you are on third tab and click on logout button then make the global variable "isLogoutClick" as true.
3.and then navigate to first tab (1st scene) and on viewDidLoad just check the condition that 
               if(appDelegate.isLogoutClick)
               {
                     push your view to next scene.
               }
4. make false the value of isLogoutClick.
5. make sure at initially the value of isLogoutClick is false.

try this might it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

After setting `selectedIndex` to `0`, perform the segue you want (in this example, `"loginSegue"`). You can name your segue in the storyboard if you haven't already.

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

if let someViewController = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? SomeViewController {
    someViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works for tabBarController because I've used this for my navigationController but should work the same.

```
if let tab = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
    if let index = find(tab.map { $0 is LoginViewController }, true) {
        let destination = tab[index] as LoginViewController
        tabBarController?.presentViewController(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

With a navigationController I would use `popToViewController` but I'm not sure how the tabBarController exactly works